# Unable to complete Azure ACS Authentication in MVC Applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-acs

I have an MVC 3 Application that I am trying to integrate with Azure-hosted ACS Identity Providers. I have been following the Tutorials but they do not appear to be working for me when using ASP.NET MVC.

Essentially, when I hit the **View** which I've flagged with `[Authorize]` the user is redirected to the Azure-hosted Login page with the list of **Identity Providers**. I choose a provider (in this case *Live*) and log in. At this point this all works as I expect. After I successfully authenticate it appears (*visually*) that I'm **not** redirected back to my application, instead I'm returned to the Identity Providers page. When watching this in Fiddler, it appears it actually returns but then starts the cycle all over again (*HTTP Status Code 302*).

Can someone explain what may be causing this?

Within the Azure portal, I have the following Urls configured for my relying party application

- **Realm**: http: //localhost:7777/
- **Return Url**: http: //localhost:7777/ (*I also tried http: //localhost:7777/Home/About*)
- In all other cases I have the default settings

The urls match what is in the Web.config (*including the trailing slash*)

There is only one controller with the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        Response.Write("Claims Received from ACS:");
        ClaimsIdentity ci = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity; foreach (Claim c in ci.Claims)
        {
            Response.Write("Type: " + c.ClaimType + "- Value: " + c.Value + "");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

***Note:** This is a brand new project created to work through this integration. All the packages and related SDKs are all up-to-date.*

Comment: If you're still up against this same issue, I'd like to see what your web.config looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know whether you mean is when you log in and return to your web application, it thinks you’re not logged in, and redirects you to the identity provider’s sign in page again.

Please check if you’ve configured the authorization logic correctly. For example, if you use role based authorization, it is needed to configure ACS to create a rule that returns a role. You can also use custom authorization instead of the Authorization attribute. In your custom authorization code, you can check if the required claims are present. The claims can be role or anything else (user name, age, etc.). Custom authorization is usually more agile than the Authorization attribute.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: I haven't done any customizations yet, I've just created a blank MVC App and referenced the Azure STS using the walkthroughs on the Azure site. I have no special claim requirements yet and did not configure any extras in the Rule Groups, just the defaults defined in your article. I've removed the `[Authorized]` attribute and just set `<deny users="?" />`. At this point, after I click *Windows Live™ ID* it just loops back since I have already authenticated correctly. Each Loop starts and ends on the Sign In page.

Comment: I can confirm that I see `Set-Cookie: FedAuth=xyz` and `Set-Cooke: FedAuth1=xyz` when the POST occures back to `localhost:7777`. The response is a 302 and the `Location:` header is then set back to the Azure entry-point. At present I am just trying to see basic Authentication work.

Comment: I recommend you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127794.aspx for a sample to see whether it helps.

Comment: I will try this but I am already following a sample on the Azure site and can't reproduce the documented result. I am not sure following yet another; even more complex; sample is really a solution but I will try none-the-less.

Comment: This did not work either and I followed the sample exactly. I got the sample to run but could never get authorized to view the contents of the *Directory* View which is what the sample is trying to demonstrate. In this case, I can see the POST back to the `SignIn` Action and the User principle is set with a `ClaimsPrinciple`, `IsAuthenticated = true`, and `AuthenticationType = "Federation"`. When I click *Directory* I'm sent through the SignIn process again.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you haven’t modified the sample code. Since it is an official ACS SDK sample, a lot of people have tried it and it will work.

Also in your original post, you mentioned you’ve configured ASP.NET authorization:

```
<authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
```

Please remove this (as indicated in the document), if you don’t want to use ASP.NET authorization(you want to use WIF).

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: I have followed the documentation precisely for three seperate examples on the Azure site and all of them result in the same condition. In the latest sample that you supplied I ran through it again with the same result. I can confirm the `<authorization>` section was removed. As for my configuration of Authorization, I originally attributed a method with the `[Authorize]` but as I stated in a previous comment, I removed that. In any case, I had the same problem with or without it.

Comment: Should I revert to pay support?